# Change the names in choices without effecting the referencing column

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny application with selectinput. At one place, i need to customize the choice names in selectinput. For example

```
iris1 <- iris
iris1$New <- paste0(iris$Species, "New")
selectInput("id","label", choices = unique(iris1$Species))
```

The above code gives you the drop down as `("setosa","versicolor", "virginica")`
But i need to be displayed the values that is there in "New" column `("setosaNew","versicolorNew", "virginicaNew")`

But when we are referencing `input$id`, it should reference to column "Species" and not "New"

Can we achieve this?

Comment: why not directly use `unique(iris1$New)` ?

Comment: No , the plan is different . These New column values are  not in another table. That another table has these values in Species column.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming another table is `iris` which does not have `New` column you can do -

```
unique(iris1$New[match(iris$Species, iris1$Species)])

#[1] "setosaNew"     "versicolorNew" "virginicaNew"
```

Comment: This does not work out. Because when i reference ````input$id````, it is referencing to ````"setosaNew"     "versicolorNew" "virginicaNew" ````

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Can you provide a reproducible example?